# Angular - ngOnChange on FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, ngonchanges

I need to detect real time changes to the fields of a `FormGroup`. I have a simple parent-child components structure as follows:

*parent component view*

```
<my-child [myForm]="myForm"></my-child>
```

*child component controller*

```
@Input()
myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
console.log('changes', changes)
}
```

The problem is that no change is detected when the form fields change. Is there a way to trigger the `ngOnChanges` to any form change?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
    // do what you need with the form fields here
    // you can access a form field via changes.fieldName
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
formName: FormGroup;      
@Input() myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const MyFormChanges: SimpleChange = changes.myForm;
    // To Check current values
    console.log(MyFormChanges.currentValue)

    // To Check previous values
    console.log(MyFormChanges.previousValue)

    // To Set Current Values to fields using controls
 this.formName.controls['email'].setValue(MyFormChanges.currentValue.email);
}
```